# Webpack bundling without using routing

Tags: angular

In My MVC Project. for say  I Have 3 modules like A.Module  B-Module c-Module in the angular8 project. I want to bundle each module separately and load separately without using routing. is it able to do using a web pack?plz give any ideas

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options, but the easiest is to use an external package that makes it a bit more simple for you.

Here you can find some simple info on how to use "Reactive Component Loader":
https://medium.com/wishtack/angular-lazy-loading-without-router-471166580c86

**An other option is t do it all yourself.**

First you need to make a "lazyModules" path in your angular.json file, so Angular can tell WebPack that it needs to create a separate module for it.

```
 {
  "projects": {
    "your-app-name": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "options": {
            "lazyModules": [
              "src/app/modules/lazy-loaded.module"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After that you need something to load the module. We can

> SystemJsNgModuleLoader

for this, just like the router does. To use it, you need to declare it in your AppModule like this:

```
import { NgModule, SystemJsNgModuleLoader, NgModuleFactoryLoader } from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    { provide: NgModuleFactoryLoader, useClass: SystemJsNgModuleLoader }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

After that you need a directive that takes the module name as an input and injects the root component in to the current ViewContainerRef.

Before you make the directive you need to create a provider that holds all your lazy loaded module paths.

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';

export type LAZY_MODULES = {
  widgetSettings: string;
};

export const lazyMap: LAZY_MODULES = {
  widgetSettings: 'src/app/modules/lazy-loaded.module#LazyLoadedModule'
};

export const LAZY_MODULES_MAP = new InjectionToken('LAZY_MODULES_MAP', {
  factory: () => lazyMap
});
```

**Now we can create the directive:**

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[loadModule]'
})
export class LoadModuleDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input('loadModule') moduleName: keyof LAZY_MODULES;
  private moduleRef: NgModuleRef<any>;

  constructor(
    private vcr: ViewContainerRef,
    private injector: Injector,
    private loader: NgModuleFactoryLoader,
    @Inject(LAZY_MODULES_MAP) private modulesMap
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loader
      .load(this.modulesMap[this.moduleName])
      .then((moduleFactory: NgModuleFactory<any>) => {
        this.moduleRef = moduleFactory.create(this.injector);
      });

  }
}
```

Now you have your module, now you only need to create a root component and inject in into your view.

There are a few ways to do this again. But the one I like best is to declare the root component as a static property on the Module you want to lazy load.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [LazyLoadedModule.rootComponent],
  entryComponents: [LazyLoadedModule.rootComponent]
})
export class LazyLoadedModule {
  static rootComponent = lazyLoadedRootComponent;
}
```

Now you can get the root component inside the directive factory you created and create the root component in the view.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.loader
    .load(this.modulesMap[this.moduleName])
    .then((moduleFactory: NgModuleFactory<any>) => {
      this.moduleRef = moduleFactory.create(this.injector);
      const rootComponent = (moduleFactory.moduleType as ModuleWithRoot).rootComponent;

      const factory = this.moduleRef.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(
        rootComponent
      );

      this.vcr.createComponent(factory);
    });
}
```

Then inside the ngOnDestroy of the directive you need to destroy the module:

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.moduleRef && this.moduleRef.destroy();
}
```

**Hope this helps a bit :)**